# Get Array size in Angular-JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to get the size of an array but every time the console say me undefined and don't know why.

```
.success(function (data) {
            console.log('Random-Suffix:' + suffix);
            $scope.builds = new X2JS().xml_str2json(data);

            var size  = $scope.builds.length;
            console.log('Size: ' + size);



            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.exampleLiveDataChange();
            }, 3000);
        })
```

Comment: What is output of `console.log($scope.builds)`?

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof($scope.builds))` you will most probably see that `$scope.builds` is not an array ! You may then need to output it and look for your array inside it;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I read in the [X2JS documentation](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/):

```
<instance>.xml_str2json - Convert XML specified as string to JSON
```

Maybe builds is not an array, but an object. If the object contains an array like this one:

```
var test = {one : 'one' , two : [1,2,3]};
```

If you do:

```
test.length;
```

You get:

```
undefined
```

If you do:

```
test.two.length;
```

Then you get:

```
3
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, thanks.
Do you know if is there a way to get the size of an array inside the object?

Comment: Yeah, it's easy. What is the structure of the object?